# mongoclient in php - trying to create and test a full text search index

Tags: php, mongodb, search, full-text-search

**Background Information**

I'm trying to write some code that will

a) delete an index
b) recreate the index
c) test the index by running a full text search.

My code is failing to run the search with an error message.

> 'no such command: text'

I'm running mongodb 3.0.4 on an ubuntu machine

**Code**

Here's the code that I have:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.1.1.111:27017");
$collection = $mongo->mytestdb->testcollection;
$db = $mongo->mytestdb;

echo "Attempting to delete text index...<BR>";
$res = $collection->deleteIndex("TextSearchIndex");
var_dump($res);
echo "Attempting to create text index...<BR>";
$res = $collection->createIndex(array("$**" => "text"), array( 'name' => "TextSearchIndex"));
var_dump($res);

echo "we will now conduct a sample text search on the words 'Mira Loma': <BR>";

$res = $db->command(
    array(
        'text' => 'testcollection', //this is the name of the collection where we are searching
        'search' => 'Mira Loma', //the string to search
        'limit' => 1000, //the number of results, by default is 1000
        'project' => Array( //the fields to retrieve from db
            'description' => 1,
            'pidnum' => 2
        )
    )
);
```

The results I see on the web page are as follows:

```
Attempting to delete text index...
array (size=3)
  'nIndexesWas' => int 2
  'ok' => float 0
  'errmsg' => string 'index not found with name [TextSearchIndex_1]' (length=45)
Attempting to create text index...
array (size=5)
  'createdCollectionAutomatically' => boolean false
  'numIndexesBefore' => int 2
  'numIndexesAfter' => int 2
  'note' => string 'all indexes already exist' (length=25)
  'ok' => float 1
we will now conduct a sample text search on the words 'Mira Loma': 
array (size=4)
  'ok' => float 0
  'errmsg' => string 'no such command: text' (length=21)
  'code' => int 59
  'bad cmd' => 
    array (size=4)
      'text' => string 'testcollection' (length=14)
      'search' => string 'Mira Loma' (length=9)
      'limit' => int 1000
      'project' => 
        array (size=2)
          'description' => int 1
          'pidnum' => int 2
```

**What I've tried so far**

I found some other posts here on stackoverflow that describe similar issues and the suggestion was to make sure text searches are enabled by adding something like this to the mongod.conf file:

```
setParameter = textSearchEnabled=true
```

I added that setting and restarted the service... but I still get the same error message.

Also, based on what I've read so far, it seems that in versions 2.6 of mongo and later, text searches are just automatically enabled.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.textSearchEnabled

**Questions:**

1. My first question is how to change this code to get the search working.
2. I'm also wondering why my attempt to delete the index is failing. It seems that the system tried to delete an index called "TextSearchIndex_1" according to the output... But in my code, I've specified "TextSearchIndex"  as the name.